# Executar query que concatene parametros (@p) no Firebird

Tags: firebird, concatenação-de-string

Estou necessitando executar uma `query` em que o valor a ser concatenado dever ser passado como parâmetro para a consulta.

```sql
SELECT t.id || @p || t.nome FROM Test t;
```

Mas ao executar esta consulta ele retorna o seguinte erro: **Dynamic SQL Error.**

No MySQL essa mesma ideia funciona da seguinte forma:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(t.id, @p, t.nome) FROM Test t;
```

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de fazer esse tipo de concatenação no Firebird? Pois pelo que percebi o operador `||` é que causa esse problema quando é utilizado um parâmetro.

> Obs¹: É necessário que o valor a ser concatenado como separador seja passado por parâmetro.
>
> Obs²: Eu sei que se eu fizer a concatenação do valor na query isso funciona, ficando a query a ser executada dessa forma: `select t.id || 'stringparaseparar' || t.nome from Test t;`, mas em meu caso como citado anteriormente é necessário que esse valor seja passado por parâmetro. Ex: set @p = 'stringparaseparar'.

**Para esclarecer melhor o motivo dessa necessidade acompanhe [essa outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31323/h%C3%A1-alguma-forma-de-setar-o-nhibernate-para-n%C3%A3o-parametrizar-uma-consulta) que descreve a origem desse problema.**

Comment: seria interessante você colocar o código do erro.

Comment: Já está explícito na pergunta: Dynamic SQL Error.

Comment: Mas existem diversos "Dynamic SQL Error". Vide [referência com códigos de erros do firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfrefdocs/Firebird-2.1-ErrorCodes.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso você deve fazer um **cast** do parâmetro para **varchar**:

```
SELECT t.id || cast(:p as varchar(10)) || t.nome FROM Test t;
```

Comment: Legal, isso funciona por incrível que pareça, hehe. O bom é que é possível continuar utilizando parâmetros ao invés de concatenação que é um tanto quanto ruim por varias questões (segurança, desempenho). Vou alterar [minha solução](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32026/2998) que está atualmente forçando o NHibernate a concatenar ao invés de parametrizar, para instrui-lo a fazer desta maneira. Obrigado pela atenção, já tinha obtido varias respostas errôneas, que até já não tinha mais esperança que isso era possível. rsrs

Comment: Sim. Neste caso você precisa informar ao Firebird qual o tipo do parâmetro que você está querendo inputar o valor.
Obs.: Esta é uma característica disponível apenas a partir da versão 2.0 do no Firebird.  Vide [Referência em inglês](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-cast.html)

Answer (score -1):

Você deveria fazer assim:

```
SELECT t.id || :p || t.nome FROM Test t;
```

e não:

```
SELECT t.id || @p || t.nome FROM Test t;
```

Comment: Isso não parece mudar em nada aqui para mim? Isso funciona para você no Firebird?

Comment: Esse parâmetro você esta passando por aplicação ? qual linguagem ?

Comment: Executei `SELECT t.id || :p || t.nome FROM Test t;` aqui no IBExpert e continua ocorrendo o mesmo problema de Dynamic SQL Error. Há algo que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: IBOConsole, a mesma coisa, e estou executando essa query através do .net, pelo framework NHibernate, em uma consulta Linq(Só que esse select que postei é uma subquery lá no contexto que utilizo);

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se entendi perfeitamente sua pergunta, mas vamos lá.

Tabela: Produto

Codigo | Nome  | Complemento
1      | Lápis | Preto
2      | Caneta| Azul

```
 Select Codigo, Nome, Complemento,  Nome|| ' COR' || Complemento as TudoJunto from Produto
```

Resultado:

1      | Lápis | Preto | Lapis COR Preto

2      | Caneta| Azul  | Caneta COR Azul

Se não for isso, post um comentário que edito aqui.

Comment: Ta mas no caso a 'COR', não está sendo passado por parâmetro, está sendo explicito na `query`. E meu problema e para o caso de ser passado por parâmetro.

Comment: @Fernando - Agora entendi. Marca um minuto aí.

Answer (score -1):

para vc testar isso no IBEXPERT ou mesmo utilizar dentro de sua aplicação voce tem que fazer uma query de uma Soted Procedure voce tem que passar para uma STORED PROCEDURE

Seu Comando Select de Origem de uma procedure fica assim:

```
Select cidade From Busca_CEP("17504110")
```

---

```
create or alter procedure BUSCA_CEP (
    PCEP integer)
returns (
    cidade varchar(60)))
as
begin
   Select CEP.cidade From CEP into :cidade;
end
```

Creio que assim resolve seu problema...

Comment: Não entendi, o que isso ajudaria a resolver o problema? O problema é a concatenação de parâmetros no comando select.

Comment: Voce esta certo mesmo...  eu que entendi a pergunta errada... me desculpe..  posso remover essa resposta

Comment: Ok, sem problemas, achei que eu não tinha entendido sua resposta, mas mesmo assim obrigado pela atenção e disposição em ajudar.