# Há alguma forma de setar o NHibernate para não parametrizar uma consulta?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate

**Problema**

Tenho uma consulta Linq com NHibernate em que em uma `subquery` necessito concatenar os resultados com um separador para compara-lo, com os da `query` principal, é algo similar ao demostrado a seguir:

```cs
IQueryable<string> queryList = (from t1 in Session.Query<Table1>()
                                where (from t2 in Session.Query<Table2>()
                                        where t2.Table1 == t1
                                        select t2.Table1.Id + "#").Contains(t1.Id + "#")
                                select t1.Nome);
// É possivel de alguma forma informar o NHibernate para não parametrizar o "#"? Já que no Firebird esse modo está me trazendo problemas.
IEnumerable<string> list = queryList.ToList();
```

Que resultaria em uma consulta similar a essa em SQL:

```sql
select T1.ID, T1.NOME
from TABLE1 T1
where (T1.ID || @ P0) in (select (T2.TABLE1_ID  || @P1)
                          from TABLE2 T2
                          where T2.TABLE1_ID = T1.ID)
```

Essa consulta executada em uma base de dados do Firebird, me gera o seguinte erro: **Dynamic SQL Error**.

> Esse problema de concatenar parâmetros no select do Firebird, já estou tentando tratar [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31304/executar-query-que-concatene-parametros-p-no-firebird).

**Pergunta**

Então gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de configurar o NHibernate para que nessa consulta ele não parametrize o parâmetros e sim concatene-os na query (No modo [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) == ON, hehe), o SQL ficando similar a esse:

```sql
select T1.ID, T1.NOME
from TABLE1 T1
where (T1.ID || '#') in (select (T2.TABLE1_ID  || '#')
                          from TABLE2 T2
                          where T2.TABLE1_ID = T1.ID)
```

Há alguma forma de configurar isso no NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Também já precisei disso, e ao meu ver não há uma forma direta de se resolver.

O que você pode tentar neste caso é criar uma função de extensão customizada para uso no Linq. Não cheguei a testar esta ideia - de qualquer forma, segue:

Primeiro, você "inventa" uma nova função de extensão que será utilizada em seus LINQ's no NHibernate quando você precisar fazer a concatenação com constantes no SQL.

```
public static class MinhasFuncoesLinq
{
    // Declara a função customizada com uma implementação pura para .NET
    public static string Concatena(this string str1, string str2)
    {
        return String.Concat(str1,str2)
    }
}
```

Em seguida, você precisa registrar o "conversor" do seu método customizado para o HQL quando ele for utilizado em Linq's do NHibernate.

```
public class ConcatenaGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public ConcatenaGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[] {ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() => MinhasFuncoesLinq.Concatena(null, null))};
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, 
        ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        // O segredo estaria aqui! 
        // A idéia é você "driblar" a geração padrão do HQL, extraindo das 
        // expressões seus valores e forçando a concatenação com constantes...
        HqlExpression exp1 = visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression();
        HqlExpression exp2 = visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression();
        if (arguments[0] is ConstantExpression) {
            exp1 = treeBuilder.Constant(((ConstantExpression)arguments[0]).Value);
        }
        if (arguments[1] is ConstantExpression) {
            exp2 = treeBuilder.Constant(((ConstantExpression)arguments[1]).Value);
        }

        return treeBuilder.Concat(exp1, exp2);
    }
}
```

Feito isso, você precisa criar um "registrador" que irá mapear a função customizada (`MinhasFuncoesLinq.Concatena`) com seu respectivo tradutor (`CustomGenerator`):

```
public class CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry: DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry():base()
    {
        RegisterGenerator(ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() => MinhasFuncoesLinq.Concatena(null, null)),
                          new ConcatenaGenerator());
    }
}
```

Por último (ufa), antes de você montar sua `SessionFactory`, colocar este registrador acima nas configurações do NHibernate:

```
(...)
nhConfig.Properties[Environment.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry] = typeof(CustomLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry).AssemblyQualifiedName
(...)
```

Feitas estas customizações com suas respectivas configurações para vigorar, você pode executar:

```
IQueryable<string> queryList = (from t1 in Session.Query<Table1>()
                                where t1.Id.Concatena("#") == "123#"
                                select t1.Nome);
```

Sei que este recurso (de incluir métodos customizados) funciona, mas confesso que não sei como o NHibernate irá renderizar esta nova forma de concatenação em específico. 
Creio que é uma alternativa para você experimentar possibilidades.

Exemplo retirado de:

- http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html

Comment: Implementei aqui e a principio funcionou como esperado (Havia alguns erros de sintaxe e nomes em seu código, mas acredito que seja pois como você citou não pode testar, então fui corrigindo conforme necessário e editei sua resposta, acompanhe a edição e revisa para ver se não fiz besteira, hehe). Não conhecia (e nunca tinha pensado) nessa possibilidade, e isso abre a outras possibilidades para novos recursos customizados no NHibernate. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Show @Fernando... peço desculpas pelo código - sou adepto do VB.NET, e mesclei informações do exemplo que citei com outros códigos que eu tinha aqui: sujeira na certa. Obrigado pelas suas edições.